# How to use sed to delete lines which have certain pattern and at some specific line range?

Tags: sed

This is the command working for me:

```
sed "50,99999{/^\s*printf/d}" the_file
```

So this command delete all the lines between 50 and 99999 which have "printf" in it and there is only whitespace before printf at the line.

Now my questions are:

1. how to replace 99999 with some meta symbol to indicate the real line number
   I tried `sed "50,${/^\s*PUTS/d}" the_file`, but it is not right.
2. how to replace "printf" with an environment variable? I tried

   set pattern printf

   sed "50,99999{/^\s*$pattern/d}" the_file

but it is not right.

Comment: In Bash, or any POSIX-ish shell, `set pattern printf` sets `$1` to `pattern` and `$2` to `printf`.  You should use `pattern=printf`. In  C shell derivatives, your notation should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed "50,${/^\s*PUTS/d}" the_file
```

this line won't work, because you used double quotes, and you need escape the dollar: `\$`  or use single quote: `'50,${/.../d}' file`

```
sed "50,99999{/^\s*$pattern/d}" file
```

this line should work.

### EDIT

wait, I just noticed that you set env var via `set`... this is not correct if you were with Bash. you should use `export PAT="PUT"` in your script.

check @Jonathan and @tripleee 's comments

Comment: `set` is correct for t?csh but given that it didn't work, you are probably correct in assuming that the OP is using a Bourne-compatible shell such as Bash.

Comment: Also `export` is useless but harmless in this context. There is no subprocess which needs to inherit this variable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a Bourne-like shell such as `bash`:

Simply define shell variables and splice them into your `sed` command string:

```bsh
endLine=99999
pattern='printf'

sed '50,'"$endLine"'{ /^\s*'"$pattern"'/d; }' the_file
```

Note that the *static* parts of the `sed` command strings are *single*-quoted, as that protects them from interpretation by the shell (which means you needn't quote `$` and `` ` ``, for instance).

You *can* put everything into a single *double*-quoted string so as to be able to embed variable references directly, but distinguishing between what the shell will interpret up front and what `sed` will interpret can get confusing quickly.

That said, using a double-quoted string for the case at hand is simple:

```bsh
sed "50,$endLine { /^\s*$pattern/d; }" the_file
```